# Grails parsing date

Tags: datetime, grails, groovy

I have a date value as Fri Feb 15 19:43:05 EST 2013
I could convert it into 2013-02-15 07:43:05 as String.
Now i need to get the date object of this String. I tried using simpleDateFormat in Groovy/Grails but it would just return the original value: Fri Feb 15 07:43:05 EST 2013

The way I am doing it is:

```
String dateCreated = dateValue.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") //required format
Date newDate = sdf.parse(dateCreated)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what you mean with 'return the original value'?

Comment: isn't your `dateCreated` contains value in required format? why you're thring to convert it twice?

Comment: it is in the required format but in String. i have database table with column type Date where it needs to go, and i need it in Date format for further date comparision.

Comment: Date has no format, it's a value, it's a date, that could have a String representation

Comment: but when i insert it into database, why it is inserting the current date value then?

Comment: please show how you're inserting it into databse

Comment: ObjectTape obj = new ObjectTape(objectId: id, DateCreated: dateCreated,.....)

Comment: Please, put this details into question, not comments. btw, it's stril not clear how you put it into database

Comment: Btw, it looks like ObjectTape a Grails domain. Do you know that Grails uses field `dateCreated` for automatic timestaming (http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/autoTimestamp.html), it means that it will be overwritten by Grails before save

Comment: If you want to know how to disable automatic timestamping or use provided value, please ask another SO question

Answer (score 1):

If you want dates without Time Zone I suggest you to look the [Joda-Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). [There's a plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time).

Look at `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime`, you can construct them passing separated values (year, month, day, hour, second).

Comment: Although you could do this without Joda, the value that you get from making Joda your standard way of handling dates and times, is priceless.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Date` instance, you just need:

```
Date dateValue = ...
String dateCreated = dateValue.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

and `dateCreated` will contain value like `2013-02-15 07:43:05`. You don't need to do anything else

Comment: ya but i need it in Date type as i have to insert it into database table where the column is of type Date...

Comment: insert it as Date itself, you don't need to convert it to any format at this case. JDBC, Hiberante, GORM supports Date